# What is "Class.new"?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand the `Sheep = Class.new` part in the following piece of code.

```
module Fence 
  Sheep = Class.new do
    def speak
      "Bah."
    end
  end
end

def call_sheep
  Fence::Sheep.new.speak
end
```

What exactly is it doing?

Comment: @Praveen_Shukla I've incorporated your comment into the question. Please be specific when asking a question.

Comment: "Class.new" is another method to define a class. http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/anonymous_class_hacks.html --- Please be more specific while asking a question.

Comment: It dereferences the constant `Class`, sends the message `new` to the resulting object, and assigns the result to the constant `Sheep`. Your question is really unclear. Which of the parts do you need help with? Do you understand what a message send is? Do you understand what a constant is? Do you understand what assignment is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`Class.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Class.html#method-c-new)

> Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given superclass (or `Object` if no parameter is given).

Furthermore,

> You can give a class a name by assigning the class object to a constant.

`Sheep` is that constant, so your code is equivalent to:

```
module Fence 
  class Sheep
    def speak
      "Bah."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that the execution context of a block passed to `Class.new` or `Module.new` is not entirely equivalent to the one of the body of the definitions using the `class` and `module` keywords. But both idioms result in the same constant assignment.

Answer (score 4):

```
Sheep = Class.new do
  def speak
    "Bah."
  end
end
```

*Class.new* is syntax for defining classes on Ruby. Above codes is the similar following:

```
class Sheep
  def speak
    "Bah."
  end
end
```